# RegExs VALIDATION

Tags: regex, react-native, validation, passwords

I have two different things password and pin. I'm looking for RegEx formate for both like below -:

**Password -:**

> 1. 1 Capital latter
> 2. 1 Small latter
> 3. 1 Special character
> 4. Min 8 digits
> 5. 3 time can't repeat any thing.
>
> I have achieved 4 points by
>
> ```
> let reg = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})"
> ```
>
> but i'm not able to achieve 5th one.

**PIN**

```
 1. 6 digit pin
 2. Only numbers
 3. Can't be use simple pin (111111,222222,...00000 and 123456, 234567 ....654321)
```

Comment: Can you add few valid and invalid examples?

Comment: Sure @anubhava,

password -: Anil@123, Patil@123 ... valid
                   Anilpatilios@123 invalid ("i" used 3 times in string)

Pin -: can be use alternate 6 digits, any things.

Comment: What have you tried for your pins? Also can you tell what exactly is not allowed?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with an additional negative lookahead to disallow 3 or more repeats of any character:

```sh
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?!.*?(.)(?:.*?\1){2}).{8,}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/syGl15/1/)

Take note of this additional negative lookahead:

```sh
(?!.*?(.)(?:.*?\1){2})
```

This will fail the match if we find 3 or more repeats of a character anywhere in input.

**Complete regex details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=.*[a-z])`: Positive lookahead to assert that we must have a small letter
- `(?=.*[A-Z])`: Positive lookahead to assert that we must have an uppercase letter
- `(?=.*[0-9])`: Positive lookahead to assert that we must have a digit
- `(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])`: Positive lookahead to assert that we must have a special character
- `(?!.*?(.)(?:.*?\1){2})`: Negative lookahead to assert that we must not 3 or more repeats of same character
- `.{8,}`: Match 8 or more characters
- `$`; End